# Load 20 items at a time with Ng-repeat Angularjs or optimize Google Markers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I am calling my api and getting coords of more than 1000 locations. Is there a why to place 20 markers at a time every like 1/2 a second with ng-repeat so that I can speed up the process? It loads all 1000+ at the same time making the markers loading time a lot slower. I am using http://ngmap.github.io/.

Here is my Controller:

```
  oxford.controller('marker',['$scope', 'companies', function($scope, companies) {
companies.success(function(data) {
   $scope.markers = data;

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            return $scope.mylocation = (position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude);
        });
        }
})
}]);
```

here is my map page:

```
    <div ng-controller="marker">
<h2>Search:</h2>
    <input type="text" ng-model="search.$" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
  <map center="37.7866983, -122.4183997" zoom="4">
      <div ng-repeat="marker in markers | filter:search track by marker.id">
        <marker position="{{ marker.latitude }},{{ marker.longitude }}" title="{{ marker.name }}" on-click="showInfoWindow(event, 'bar')"></marker>
          <info-window id="bar" visible-on-marker="foo">
            <div ng-non-bindable="">
              <div id="siteNotice"></div>
              <h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">{{ marker.name }}</h1>
              <div id="bodyContent">
                <p><b>{{ marker.address }}</b></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </info-window>
      </div>
  </map>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you really need to load all the markers? Check out the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#fusiontables) for optimizing when you have too many markers. I think MarkerClusters would be best, but there are other techniques like only loading the markers visible in the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Store your location data in an array or list, then run a for loop running 20 items a time, for example:

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i=i+20){
   //run a function that adds markers with index i to i+20
}
```

Or do a setTimeOut function to update the index every half seconds until it adds all the given markers. Hope this gives you some idea.